# Google spreadsheet, how to join text and keep format of each text

Tags: google-sheets

For example: I have "A1" = "Today" (in red color), "A2" = "Monday" (bold font).

I tried to concatenate them and keep format, like A3 = A1 & " is " A2.

I tried below things and does not work:
1/ Using & operator: seem like it not able to keep text format.
2/ Using Concatenate() function + Text(A1,"Red") -> does not work.
3/ Using To_Text() function.

Thank you!

Comment: Function can't give you those formats. You need to manually reformat to resultant cell.